# R Shiny: Error Pushing Repository 504 Status when deploying App to Shinyapps

Tags: r, shiny

When I run `rsconnect::deployApp()`, the process starts as usual, but it fails before it finishes deploying the app. 
The total size of the app is just below 1GB. Could it be possible that that is the cause?

I am sitting behind a corporate proxy, which seems like a plausible cause given the 504 error code, but I am able to upload other dashboards.

For that same reason I do not believe the issue to be related to the packages I am using, since I have uploaded dashboards using the same packages.

```
Uploading bundle for application: 216693...DONE
Deploying bundle: 989255 for application: 216693 ...
Waiting for task: 488988796
  building: Processing bundle: 989255
  building: Parsing manifest
  building: Building image: 987117
  building: Fetching packages
  building: Installing packages
  building: Installing files
  building: Pushing image: 987117
################################ Begin Task Log ################################ 
[2017-09-20T13:47:27.471530928+0000] Installing R package: viridisLite (0.2.0)
* installing to library ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
* installing *binary* package ‘viridisLite’ ...
* DONE (viridisLite)

TRUNCANTED FOR CLARITY

[2017-09-20T13:47:38.089874978+0000] Installing R package: reshape2 (1.4.2)
* installing to library ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
* installing *binary* package ‘reshape2’ ...
* DONE (reshape2)
[2017-09-20T13:47:38.310895197+0000] Installing R package: bindrcpp (0.2)
* installing to library ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
* installing *binary* package ‘bindrcpp’ ..################################# End Task Log ################################# 
Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 488988797 error: Unhandled Exception: Error pushing repository: Received HTTP code 504 while uploading layer: "<html>\r\n<head><title>504 Gateway Time-out</title></head>\r\n<body bgcolor=\"white\">\r\n<center><h1>504 Gatewa
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue was in the size of the upload, as soon as I reduced that, I was able to get my dashboard online.