# Shiny "unknown blob" error when deploying

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, shinyapps

all

I'm trying to update an old Shiny app, and when I try to deploy, I get

> Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 668199638 error: Unhandled Exception: Error pushing repository: unknown blob

I don't even know what that error means, let alone how to correct it. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Possibly related? https://stackoverflow.com/q/46324733 (probably not ...)

Comment: I would try and comment out sections and run over and over until you can identify which specific line is causing it, then you'll have a bit more to go on troubleshooting wise

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, according to the RStudio folks, this is a transient error. As with all good technical things, the correct response was to quit RStudio, restart, and redeploy. It all worked.